# Should encryption key be stored remotely?

Tags: encryption, storage, sensitive-data-exposure

Consider the following scenarios of storing sensitive data locally on a network connected always-on device:

1. without any data encryption whatsoever
2. with encryption, the key stored locally in the device
3. with encryption, the key stored on a remote location accessible via network

No matter where the key is stored, once the attacker gets physical access to the device, they can obtain the key and decrypt the data. Does storing the  encryption key remotely provide any advantage in terms of data security, or are all three scenarios effectively equivalent?

Comment: What kind of data is encrypted? For what purpose? Is it full disk encryption? Is it an encrypted container mounted as storage? Is it decrypted at boot and subsequently accessible by the entire system?

Comment: @svin83 let's consider binary data on an encrypted partition mounted and decrypted at boot, but I do not consider these variables to be too significant

Comment: Decrypted at boot is essentially the same as clear text as long as the computer is running... If it is decrypted only when in use and then re-encrypted immediately after use, it is something completely different...

Comment: I think the answer depends on what are the powers that your adversary can have? If an adversary can get a memory dump during the decryption process, then its pointless where you store the key.

Comment: @svin83 immediate re-encryption would be possible, I did not consider this scenario. But, I cannot see how much is it different. If the attacker grabs the device, probably has the key as well, or not?

Comment: Secure your key with a pass phrase?

Comment: Maybe store it on a USB dongle? You could even create a program that generates the key after input of a valid single-use-auth code.

Comment: I wanted to know if what I am planning to do is worth the hassle. I have learned in the process that the term I am looking for I believe is **data-at-rest encryption**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping the key on the device is your best option *if* you have a secure place to put it. Network transport provides a much larger attack surface, even if you use TLS to transfer the key.

The usual problem is that with physical access you can easily dump the key by dumping firmware. Many embedded systems handle this with a secure key storage peripheral, either using an on-chip feature like ARM TrustZone, or an off-chip device such as Microchip's CryptoAuthentication ICs. This then acts as an oracle that can perform operations using that key (with certain defined restrictions) without ever revealing it.

Implementing this safely in practice is extremely difficult, though. It is often possible to break a lot of on-chip security features either through misconfiguration, bugs, or glitching attacks on the ICs themselves.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please add a little bit information about TPM? My currently limited research tells me it is a little bit related.

Comment: @peter.babic A TPM is a trusted platform module. They're common on x86 platforms (you probably have one in your computer) and they have a similar role to what I described above, but they have a *significantly* greater function set than just key storage. They implement things like Secure Boot, measured boot and attestation, platform integrity validation, and HRNG / key generation.